# Cannot run rails server locally wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, ubuntu-20.04

I recently install ruby 2.7.1 using rbenv. I have made sure that `.ruby-version` and Gemfile file both have 2.7.1 as ruby version.
Now i cannot run rails s locally, doing so returns the following output in console:

> Warning: the running version of Bundler (2.1.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (2.1.4). We suggest you to upgrade to the version that created the lockfile by running `gem install bundler:2.1.4`.
> Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.1

I have been searching and trying different things for hours but cannot figure out the problem and would be thankful for help.

Following output may help figure out the problem:

1. `curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash`

> Checking for `rbenv' in PATH: /usr/bin/rbenv   Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: OK   Checking` rbenv install' support: /home/imran/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin/rbenv-install (ruby-build 20200819)
> Counting installed Ruby versions: 1 versions
> Checking RubyGems settings: OK
> Auditing installed plugins: OK

2. `bundle env`

### Environment

```
Bundler       2.1.4
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby          2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9cec0d0ffcba012279cd652d28ad5bf3) [x86_64-linux]
  Full Path   /home/imran/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /home/imran/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/etc
RubyGems      3.1.2
  Gem Home    /home/imran/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  Gem Path    /home/imran/.gem/ruby/2.7.0:/home/imran/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  User Home   /home/imran
  User Path   /home/imran/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  Bin Dir     /home/imran/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin
Tools         
  Git         2.25.1
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       rbenv 1.1.1
  chruby      not installed
```

### Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2020-01-05
Git SHA           32a4159325
Released Version  true
```

3. `gem env`

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
- RUBY VERSION: 2.7.1 (2020-03-31 patchlevel 83) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/imran/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
- USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/imran/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/imran/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/ruby
- GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/imran/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/imran/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/imran/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:

  - /home/imran/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - /home/imran/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:

  - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:

  - /home/imran/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin
  - /usr/lib/rbenv/libexec
  - /home/imran/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
  - /home/imran/.rbenv/bin
  - /home/imran/.rbenv/shims
  - /home/imran/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
  - /home/imran/.rbenv/bin
  - /home/imran/.local/bin
  - /home/imran/bin
  - /usr/local/sbin
  - /usr/local/bin
  - /usr/sbin
  - /usr/bin
  - /sbin
  - /bin
  - /usr/games
  - /usr/local/games
  - /snap/bin
  - /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux

4. my `~/.profile` contains following statements:

   export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
   export GEM_HOME="$(ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')"
   export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 0):

Did You try to just update bundler as output said:

```
gem install bundler:2.1.4
```

or

```
gem install bundler
bundle update
```

Answer (score 0):

`rbenv` creates shims based on version of ruby you install. Each time you change ruby version via `rbenv global X.Y.Z` or `rbenv local A.B.C`, rbenv will intercept the ruby command and redirect it to the appropriate ruby installation version which will look at its associated gems.

Therefore, if you set your local version to `2.7.1`, and the error message you receive is telling you that your bundle version is different, you probably have not installed the `bundler` gem in the `2.7.1` Ruby shim.

To fix this, you can change your ruby version and install the gem:

```sh
rbenv local 2.7.1
ruby -v
# 2.7.1
gem install bundler
```

Now, ensure that in your Gemfile.lock you are using the same `bundler` version of the bundler gem you installed. If it is not, it means that the `Gemfile.lock` file was generated and bundled with a previous version. You can force update the `Gemfile.lock` by deleting and rebuilding, however, if you are collaborating with other developers you may want to speak with them before you do (and commit to source control)

```rb
#Gemfile.lock

BUNDLED_WITH 2.1.5
```